Git integration is not pushing automatically in Statamic
I have an issue with Statamic where the git integration isn't automatically pushing changes.
Things I've checked:

We have a valid PRO licence.

Our Forge ENV looks like this:
STATAMIC_STACHE_WATCHER=true
STATAMIC_STATIC_CACHING_STRATEGY=null
STATAMIC_REVISIONS_ENABLED=false
STATAMIC_GRAPHQL_ENABLED=false
STATAMIC_API_ENABLED=false
STATAMIC_GIT_ENABLED=true


I can manually SSH into the server and type: git push --porcelain and the push executes without any errors.

There are no errors in the laravel.log file.


What am I missing?

This was a simple gotcha. You need both STATAMIC_GIT_ENABLED and STATAMIC_GIT_PUSH set to true for git pushes. The second was missing from our ENV.
Explanation
STATAMIC_GIT_ENABLED enables git commits only. This means any time the content is changed via the user interface it will be automatically turned into an individual commit with a custom git message specified in config/statamic/git.php.
STATAMIC_GIT_PUSH actually enables automatic pushing of these commits using SSH credentials on your remote server.
You need both, not just the first one, if you want commits to be pushed into your repository.
